# Передача данных на другую страницу из input js

Tags: javascript, html, input, url

Помогите пожалуйста. Вот код:
HTML(первая страница):

````
```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input id = "input" type="text">
    <input type="button" onclick="r()" value="Пиши!">
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```
````

JS(первая страница):

````
```
function r(){
    var input = document.getElementById("input");
    var input2 = input.toString();
    window.location.href = "index2.html?name=" + input2;
}
```
````

HTML(вторая страница):

````
```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="index2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```
````

JS(вторая страница):

````
```
let par = (new URL(document.location)).searchParams;
document.write(par.get("name"));
```
````

И на второй странице выводится [object HTMLInputElement].
Как мне эту запись([object HTMLInputElement]) превратить в слова?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно правильно пользоваться свойствами и методами DOM.

Вот это не надо:

```
input.toString();
```

Вот это надо:

```
input.value;
```

---

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#file_inputs

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!